# How to fire a callback after XML properties set in Android custom view?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created an Android custom view, `MyCustomView`, that has a property of class `MySpecialClass` that is set through XML.

```xml
<com.example.MyCustomView
  app:mySpecialValue="@{viewModel.mySpecialValue}" />
```

```kotlin
class MyCustomView(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet) : ConstraintLayout(context, attributes) {
  lateinit var mySpecialValue: MySpecialClass

  override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    Log.d("Tag", ${this::mySpecialValue.isInitialized})
    // Prints true - mySpecialValue is initialized!
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
  }
}
```

I would like to execute some code soon after `mySpecialValue` is initialized. It isn't initialized in the constructor or in a few other lifecycle methods I've tried (`onFinishInflate`, `onAttachedToWindow`). Is there any event or lifecycle method that would be a good place to do this (better than `onMeasure`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use android [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) and create a setter for `mySpecialValue` in custom view class.

```
fun setSpecialValue(value: mySpecialClass) {
    // your logic
}
```

XML:

```
<com.example.MyCustomView
  app:setSpecialValue="@{viewModel.mySpecialValue}" />
```